# Unix file permissions, WARNING: can't access

Tags: unix, file-permissions

I'm trying to change the permissions of a few files that are used with a webpage I'm uploading to my site. I'm using the Unix command line to do it.

I've tried two commands:

```
chmod 755 index.html
chmod 644 index.html
```

But I get the message

```
chmod: WARNING: can't access index.html
```

after using these commands for some reason, and I have no idea why... initially I though it might be because I had the file open in a couple of programs (text editor and web browser), but I've closed these down, and I'm still getting the same problem... any idea why, and how I can set the permissions correctly so that the file will be viewable by anyone on the web, but only editable by me?

Cheers!

Comment: It's too bad the `chmod` command is not telling you the specific error that is preventing it from accessing `index.html`. Try `ls -l index.html` and see if `ls` can access it. Logically, it won't be able to, but `ls` ought to give you a more informative error message.

Comment: what flavor unix are you using and what is the location of this file?  also like @Celada said, please do a ls -l to see what the permissions are for this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link that looks similar to your problem but it's on Solaris:

http://www.unix.com/solaris/45229-unable-chmod-file-directory.html

The solution is on pg 2 of this thread but the Cliff's note version of the solution is the person found that something else was mounting at that directory.  It showed up when they ran

```
df -k /their_dir_location
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

another possible issue is ... if you are using solaris zones  .. the directory visiable in more than one zone but only one zone has write abilities.

Comment: There's nothing in the original post indicating use of Solaris.

Comment: I have same problem on Solaris, so it may be specific to this operating system. SOLUTION: the file was nonexistent.